# BackTrack USB Wireless adapter drivers issue

Tags: drivers, usb, wifi, backtrack, realtek

I purchased USB Wireless adapter which runs smoothly on **Windows** and **Ubuntu**, but in BackTrack it's showing me a **Bad password** issue. From my reading I guess it's driver issue which BackTrack Kernel don't have drivers for RTL8191SU (my) Adapter.

The Realtek site have drivers for kernels `2.6-2.9`. Even thought BackTrack 5R3 comes with `3.2.6`, I tried to compile drivers which failed for me with **make** errors.

Additionally I can't get monitor mode in aircrack suite.

Comment: Why are you using backtrack? It is a dead project. Use Kali Linux instead if needed.

Comment: Furthermore, both are just ubuntu with a bunch of packages preloaded. If it works in ubuntu, just install the tools you want on ubuntu.

Comment: On Linux, you normally don't (need to) go to a vendor's website for drivers. If your distribution is not that old, the drivers are available as part of the Linux kernel. To me it sounds more like a configuration issue, but the information you give is insufficient to help. e.g. which *application* is showing the *Bad password* error and what did you do when executing `make` when compiling the driver -- the latter should go into a separate question. My recommendation would be to try Kali Linux and close this question!

Answer (score 0):

Since your adapter works well on both windows and Ubuntu, it should also work on your BackTrack. Now that you get the bad password issue, the first thing you should do is to check your password and maybe you can try the generic driver. By the way, how about the encrypting program? If that break down, the adapter will always show you bad password errors.

Comment: try generic driver? Can you give me more info? what you mean by encrypting program?

Comment: In the kernel driver list, there should be a "generic driver" item used for the device that is not in the device list. To connect to your wireless, your computer will encrypt your password and then send it to check. If the encryption break down, you will not succeed to connect.

Comment: 1) Mention the full/approximate path, I don't see any generic driver. I tried compat-wireless drivers to compile which failed to do for my chipset. 2) Crypting is performed by Wicd manager. Hence I don't have anything to do with it.